# Efficient Way to Zero Rows with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mask

I am using OpenCV 2.2 on Windows 7.

I am making a mask where the rows are all 1 up to row 400 and 0 for rows beyond that.  I initialize the mask with cv::Mat::ones() and was wondering what would be the most efficient way to zero the rows beyond 400.  I could use for loops but was wondering if there was a more efficient, tidier way to do it.

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 6):

There is more than one way to do it:

First, sub-matrices

```
Mat bigImg(width, height, CV_8UC3);
bigImg(Rect(0,0,width, height/2)) = Scalar::all(1); // upper half ones
bigImg(Rect(0,height/2,width, height/2)) = Scalar::all(0); // lower half zeros
```

Or you can use the `RowRange` and `ColRange` for the same effect

```
bigImg(rowRange, colRange) = Scalar::all(n);
```

Just check the docs on how to use ranges

Comment: good! if you're happy with it, feel free to accept/upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to create a matrix of 400xm with `cv::Mat::ones()` and a matrix of 400x(n-m) with `cv::Mat::zeros()` and then join the two together. However this has the overhead of making the two matrices and then resizing one to be big enough to contain the other.

I think looping is definitely more efficient. It's C/C++ anyway I assume, and that's about the fastest way for this particular sort of operation.

Comment: I'm currently looping.  Thanks.